# How to send select input data for form submission?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am loading `Select` input data from viewbag. but when click on `seach` button it is throwing an error at `Viewbag.Events`. How can pass `eventcode` from form submission to index post method? any other alternatives

```
<div class="col-md-6">
<form asp-action="Index">
    <div class="row mb-3">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
                       
            <div class="input-group">
                <select class ="form-control" id="eventCode" name="eventCode"  data_placeholder="Enter event code for search" class="chosen-select">
                    @foreach (var item in ViewBag.Events)
                    {
                        <option value="@item">@item</option>
                    }
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You've got 11,000 reputation and over 500 questions posted. I'd hope you'd know that when you say "it is throwing an error" you'd want to actually include what the error is. Please see [mre].